# Why does OpenCV's deep learning face detector not work on images that are rotated to one side?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, opencv3.0

I have tried out [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/#download-the-code) tutorial on OpenCV's deep learning face detector model but am running into an issue with images that are rotated. It does not work on images like the one below. For context I have roughly 10,000 images that are rotated like this and I need to detect the faces and then crop them out.

[image]

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
# by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0,
    (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
# predictions
print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for the
        # object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
 
        # draw the bounding box of the face along with the associated
        # probability
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Because the Caffe model you are using is not trained to do so. Or is it? You can train it to rotated images or you need to rotate de image until a face is detected.

Comment: @iGian that's what I am wondering because based on my research it should be the best option for detecting faces even when they are slanted or occluded. I will just rotate all these images then if I am unable to find a solution.